# Editing array in state adds a new element instead of updating the existing (react JS)

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a odd issue with state going on and can't seem to figure out why this is happenning.

I have a function to handle form input for selections and I want to update the existing selection with the new value provided by the user in the input field.

I have come up with a function that works but instead of just editing the existing row, it's also adding a new row to the array with the updated value. Obviously, this is not what I am after, I just want the array returned with the original data updated.

Below is my function:

```
const handleSelectionInput = (e) => {
    // set id of the input being edited
    const id = e.target.id;

    // the id consists of 3 parts, 1 = the index of the breakout array
    // 2 = the index of the selection list array
    // 3 = whether its the name of the selection or the capacitiy ex: 0_0_key
    let breakoutIndex = parseInt(id.slice(0, id.indexOf("_")));
    let selectionIndex = parseInt(id.slice(id.indexOf("_") + 1, id.lastIndexOf('_')));
    let updateValue = id.slice(id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, -1);
    console.log(breakoutRow[breakoutIndex]);

    // get the breakout associated wtih the selections
    let allBreakouts = breakoutRow;
    let currentBreakout = allBreakouts[breakoutIndex];
    currentBreakout["selection"][selectionIndex].key = e.target.value;
    allBreakouts[breakoutIndex] = currentBreakout;
    // if value is key update the state of the input fields

    console.log(allBreakouts);
    if (updateValue === "ke") {
        setBreakoutRow(prevBreakouts => (
             // this returns the updated value but also adds to the array?
            [...prevBreakouts, prevBreakouts[breakoutIndex] = currentBreakout]
        )

        );
    }
    console.log(breakoutRow);

}
```

How would I be able to just return the updated array and not add a new element to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I needed to map the existing fields and update them there:

```
if (updateValue === "ke") {
        setBreakoutRow(prevBreakouts => (prevBreakouts.map((breakout, index) => {
            console.log(prevBreakouts.indexOf());
            if (prevBreakouts.indexOf() === breakoutIndex) {
                return currentBreakout;
            }
            return breakout;
        })
        )

        );
    }
```